# JSON object being returned should be array

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, fetch

I am using backbone and my fetch was not returning anything (when I tried to iterate with `each`), I had a close look and found that it fires a get request and this is what is being returned

```
{
    "-JA2Ey5xJvV-BfvgmzT3": {
        "date": "10-23-33",
        "title": "le shmow",
        "content": "testing lez post!"
    },
    "-JA2Ey6FwK5eK9mELCnd": {
        "date": "10-23-33",
        "title": "test post",
        "content": "testing lez post!"
    }
}
```

According to backbones documentation:

`The server handler for fetch requests should return a JSON array of models.`, the chrome dev toolkit has these labelled as objects? So could this be the problem?

EDIT backbone docs state:

Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, setting them on the collection when they arrive. The options hash takes success and error callbacks which will both be passed (collection, response, options) as arguments. When the model data returns from the server, it uses set to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass {reset: true}, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) reset. Delegates to Backbone.sync under the covers for custom persistence strategies and returns a jqXHR. The server handler for fetch requests should return a JSON array of models.

```
    console.log(posts.fetch());

    posts.fetch();

    console.log(posts);

    posts.each(function(post) {
        console.log(post.get("title"));
    });
```

The first console log displays a set of "objects", with the correct data etc, the second one is labelled `r` (no idea what that means?) and only has a length of 0 and I can't see the data within it.

When I used each to iterate over it, I get nothing

**EDIT:** got it working(sort of), still have no idea why i need this hack for what should be a straightforward operation...perhaps im doing something seriously wrong. Is there anyway I could edit the parse function so I just have to type `post.title` instead of `post.attributes.title`

```
 var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: base_url + '/posts.json',
      parse: function(response) {
        return _.map(response, function(model, key) {
          //i'm assuming the key of each object is the id of the model
          model['id'] = key;
          return model;
        });
      }
});

posts = new Posts;

posts.fetch().complete(function() {
    posts.each(function(post) {
        console.log(post.attributes.title);
    });
});
```

Comment: Side note: Does backbone really call it a "JSON array"?  Because, there's no such thing.  Nor is there a "JSON object".  JSON is a data transport format; a *string*.  It can *represent* an array (or an object), but it itself is not.  What I think the docs are trying to say is: "return an array of models in JSON format".

Comment: Yes that's an object, a hash of objects. That's all we can say without the context.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes that was copied direct from their documentation...

Comment: @Melbourne2991: Ok.  I understand it, I just don't like how it's worded.  Anyway, how are you making this JSON?  Note that JSON does not support "associative arrays", it only supports numeric arrays.

Comment: Makes sense, I edited the post and added more information

Comment: Your assumption in your question was right.  Backbone wants an array, not an object.  I don't know anything about backbone, but I assume it's expecting to get `[{"date":"","title":"","content":""},{"date":"","title":"","content":""}]`.

Answer (score 4):

As the document states, your server has to return an array of models in JSON format, in order to make your collection.fetch() work.

if you cannot change the server response, you will want to use parse method to convert the response to an array.

so in your collection definition:

```
YourCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  parse: function(response) {
    return _.map(response, function(model, key) {
      //i'm assuming the key of each object is the id of the model
      model['id'] = key;
      return model;
    });
  }
});
```

for more information about parse, see: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Comment: So what the server is returning isn't JSON?  @Rocket Hazmat just told me json arrays are non existance? bit confused here..

Comment: @Melbourne2991 The server should returns a JSON string  which is parsed into a Javascript structure, and that structure in the case of a collection should be an array. `Collection.parse` should convert whatever you have (an object here) to an array.

Comment: if the server is not returning JSON, then the solution depends on what kind of format the server responds, by default backbone is expecting a json response, you can overwrite Backbone.sync to make it work with XML or other formats, but ultimately, you will want to parse the response to json.

Comment: hmm unfortinately neither this solution not @nikoshr are allowing me to iterate over with each :/. Can you tell me what the server is returning? Also from what I understood from the docs, firebase (the server I am using) seems to only deal in JSON, there's not mention of other formats

Comment: @Melbourne2991 in terms of your question about JSON, during data transfer, JSON is nothing but a string. JSON itself is language-independent, JavaScript takes the string, and converts it to Objects and Arrays that it can use easily.

Comment: each definitely works, as long as your model and collection are set up correctly. see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucZx5/1/

Comment: @Melbourne2991 Probably because you're using `each` just after `fetch` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427 and try `posts.fetch().then(function() {posts.each...})`

Comment: @Melbourne2991: Sorry if I confused you.  I just meant the *term* "JSON array" is incorrect.  The correct term is just "JSON" or "JSON string"/"JSON data".